# JavaFX2: TableView with different Sources for TableData

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to get Data of 2 different ObservableLists in one TableView (2 Colums), but havnt found a solution for now.

I got 2 Lists, each holding elements of a special DataType.

I need 2 get Parameter Name out of Datatype A in OL1 und Parameter zone of Datatype B in OL2.
A and B are both SimpleStringProperty.

ObservableList 1 und 2 always got the same length.

I know i can get the parameters out of the lists with PropertyValueFactory, but i cannot use different sources.

Is there a hint u can give me?

Comment: can you explain in detail what exactly you want to do ?
then i would be help you

Comment: i got 2 datatyps
datatype subtance with simplestringproperty Name (and others) and
datatype zones with simplestringproperty Status (and others)

i want a single tableview with Name out of substance in Column A and  Status out of zones in Column B

so i cant use just TableView.setItems(xy) cause i got 2 Sources

Comment: use of two observation list its not possible  but you can add both datatypes values from different files into observation list by pass reference file to another file..and access from one file to another file value

Comment: thanks for the hint. i will just use this workaround. i just hoped there is a possibility to access directly the two observablelists. but adding both to another file works well to

Comment: yep i do it already...i am mapping both files and easily acess both in one observation list and get the desire fields according my need.